# font modification inside array object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to modify font size and font type inside an object in an array. It's in a DOM. My lines on font family and font size don't seem to work. Can you help on the right syntax, please?

```
const ironCurtainQuiz = [
  {
    question: "The camera footage has arrived back at base. The number one priority is to show it to:",
    options: ["The president.", "The Pentagon.", "The CIA."],
    answer: 0,
    background: "./../images/image-question-1.jpg",
    fontSize: "28px",
    fontFamily: "Courier, Courier New, Serif",
  },
]
```

Comment: Please provide the relevant part of the generated HTML page. More complete code can also help...

Answer (score 0):

here simple way to update array of object value thanks :-)

```js
const ironCurtainQuiz = [
  {
    question: "The camera footage has arrived back at base. The number one priority is to show it to:",
    options: ["The president.", "The Pentagon.", "The CIA."],
    answer: 0,
    background: "./../images/image-question-1.jpg",
    fontSize: "28px",
    fontFamily: "Courier, Courier New, Serif",
  },
]

ironCurtainQuiz[0].fontSize = '58px'
ironCurtainQuiz[0].fontFamily = 'ROBOTO'

console.log(ironCurtainQuiz)
```